# How to limit access to individual files in an Amazon s3 static website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, bucket

Recently created a static website, hosted on s3 and I noticed when users check the source of the website, they can click links which allow them to access items such as images in a separate tab. Is there a way to allow the website to access the images but to limit users trying to access the source image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user simply opening assets in a tab should be fine, if you're simply trying to prevent the content from accessible other than on your domain you can use the `Referer` head to lock it down to only via your web site.

This can be done in S3 via a [bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html) [similar to the one below](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4).

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Id":"http referer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.example.com/*","http://example.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can always enhance this by using a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) combined with a [AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to included a rule to block by referrer.

If you're trying to lock this content (whether someone needs to either login to see it or pay to get it) you have a couple of options.

- You can create [pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html) for your S3 objects and expose these in the HTML. This will be valid for a limited time (depending on the parameters passed into the generation).
- You can use a CloudFront distribution with [either signed cookies or signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html).

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you can't limit ability to download your images without proper authentication. If your users can see images in their browsers, they can download them, as they've had been already downloaded.

But you can limit your users from **directly going to your S3** bucket. For this you can front your S3 bucket with [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) (CF).

Specifically, you could setup `Origin Access Identity` in CF and make your website and all images accessible only through CF:

- [Restricting Access to Amazon S3 Content by Using an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)
- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)
- [How do I use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)